# Slowing the animation to the end on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I use a counter that linearly counts numbers through animation at a constant rate. I want to know if it's possible to slow down the animation of the estimate closer to the end.

```
<h1 class="counter" data-count="2200">0</h1>
```

---

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },
  {
    duration: 4000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
    }

  });  
});
```

For example: if the animation of the counter is completed more than half, the animation will slow by 50%.

Comment: The duration is how long the animation will take (ms), increase that value to slow the animation down.

Comment: @Esko I need to increase the duration, depending on the "progress" of the counter. I do not know how to implement this in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an easing effect.

> Easing
>
> The remaining parameter of .animate() is a string naming an easing
>   function to use. An easing function specifies the speed at which the
>   animation progresses at different points within the animation. The
>   only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default,
>   called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called
>   linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins,
>   most notably the jQuery UI suite.

By default Jquery has two easing functions. You can use `swing` to get something close to what you expect.

But it slows down the animation at the beginning and at the end.

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },
  {
    duration: 4000,
    easing:'swing',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
    }

  });  
});
```

==========================================================

## Edit:

Answer to the comment: I think you can do the same using the `step` function. You can check if the animation is completed halfway, and then animate it again from that point with a new duration.

Here's an example:

```
$('.counter').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

    var animation = {
        countNum: countTo
    };

    $({ countNum: $this.text() }).animate(animation, {
        duration: 4000,
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            if (fx.pos > 0.5) {
                $(this).stop();
                $(this).animate(animation, {
                    duration: 5000,
                    step: function () {
                        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $this.text(this.countNum);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/z86pf27q/19/

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that this effect is noticeable when the value of the counter is small. But for large values, the effect is minimal. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/58630/)

Comment: Thank you very much! it helped me.